# Typescript json references variable but need check if variable exists

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some json code within a function that looks like this:

```
getFields(name: string) {
   this.json_data = [
      {
        "e_name": "fake_c",
        "fields": [
          {
            "f_name": "c_name",
            "title": "K C Name",
            "c_name": "cname",
            "path": this.dialogData.name
          },
          {
            "f_name": "c_number",
            "title": "K C Number",
            "c_name": "cnumber",
            "path": this.dialogData.c_id
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "e_name": "other_c",
        "fields": [
          {
            "f_name": "c_name",
            "title": "K C Name",
            "c_name": "cname",
            "path": this.dialogData.r_name
          },
          {
            "f_name": "c_address",
            "title": "K C Address",
            "c_name": "caddress",
            "path": this.dialogData.r_address
          },
          {
            "f_name": "c_number",
            "title": "K C Number",
            "c_name": "cnumber",
            "path": this.dialogData.r_number
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
   return this.known_company_mapping.filter((d)=> d.entity_name === name).map((res) => res.fields)[0]
```

As you can see, based on the e_name, I am filtering the json.

However, my code is breaking due to the `path` that refers to dialogData.

When `e_name` is equal to 'fake_c', then the dialogData follows the structure that is used in the 'fake_c' paths, eg it contains a `name` and `c_id` component.

However, when 'fake_c' is used, then the paths for `other_c` breaks as the dialogData doesn't have `r_name` for example. When 'fake_c' is being used, I'm not interested in the paths for 'other_c'.

Is there any way I can make the path equal to null if the variable doesn't exist?

I've tried the below with no success:

```
"path": if(this.dialogData.r_name) {this.dialogData.r_name} else {''}
```

And also the below:

```
"path": this.dialogData.r_name ? this.dialogData.r_name : ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following quick if must work:

```
(this.dialogData.r_name ? this.dialogData.r_name : "")
```

as you can see in the example below.

make sure that your program re-built after each try,
and that the quick if is actually running using

```
debugger;
```

or breakpoints.

```js
this.dialogData={};
this.dialogData.r_name="test";
console.log({"path": (this.dialogData.r_name ? this.dialogData.r_name : "")});
this.dialogData.r_name=undefined;
console.log({"path": (this.dialogData.r_name ? this.dialogData.r_name : "")});
```